# How to compare multiple numbers from the output of task and print something in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**example.txt:**

```
total tests passed : 0 in last run
number of test passed : 0 in yesterday
sent report for passed : 0 in tests
```

**Please NOTE : This file won't be limited to 3 lines as shown above. Sometime there will be only one line. And sometime it will be more than three lines.**

Now my job is to :

TASK 1 : Grep all "Passed : " count

Example output:

```
0
23
0
```

TASK 2 : If any one of the "passed count is NOT EQUAL TO zero" then print "TASK Completed"

Example output:

```
TASK Completed
```

I have tried with following Python code:

```
import re
test = open("test.txt", 'r')

for i in test:
    output = re.match('.*(passed :)(.*) (in)', i)
    if output:
        print output.group(2)
```

Now I am able to print all "passed : " count (TASK 1).

How to compare all these values and if any one value is NOT EQUAL TO zero then print as "TASK COMPLETED"?

Any idea on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

PASSED = re.compile(r" passed : (\d+)")

def get_passed_values(s):
    for match in PASSED.finditer(s):
        yield int(match.group(1))   # return the number as an integer

def is_complete(s):
    return any(v > 0 for v in get_passed_values(s))

with open("test.txt") as test:
    s = test.read()
    if is_complete(s):
        print("TASK COMPLETED")
    else:
        raise ValueError("All 0s!")
```

**Edit:** I added a 'raise exception on all 0s' clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am not getting any output. I mean its not print anything. could you please check once?

Comment: Sorry I got the output now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any idea on how to "raise Exception" if all numbers are zero?

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
completed = False
for i in test:
    output = re.match('.*(passed :)(.*)', i)
    if output:
        print output.group(2)
        if not output.group(2) == "0":
            completed = True
if completed:
   print "TASK COMPLETED"
```

--

### edit

So you also need the regexp to separate the numbers out,

Try

```
re.match( r'.*(passed : )(\d*)(.*)', i )
```

this means, find "passed : " followed by any number of digits, followed by any other text.
The digits should be grouped as match-group 2 as you desire.

Comment: sorry I forgot the not!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my script was printing numbers and some texts. So it was not printing the numbers correctly. I have modified th e text file contents and my python code

Comment: I have tried your code... But its printing TASK COMPLETED even its zero in all numbers (Please NOTE : I have considered "not equal to !="). Any clue please?

Comment: If all numbers are zero.. its printing as TASK COMPLETED :). Could you please check once.